# Erro The multi-part identifier "..." could not be bound

Tags: sql, transações

Estou tentando fazer o seguinte select e ele me retorna o erro The multi-part identifier "..." could not be bound na ImportaContratoAux.ContratoId

```
select AreaReclamacao.Descricao from AreaReclamacao 
inner join Contrato on Contrato.Id = ImportaContratosAux.ContratoId
inner join ImportaContratosAux on ImportaContratosAux.EmpresaId = AreaReclamacao.EmpresaId 
where Contrato.Id = '4100001124'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O erro é porque vc está tentando acessar um campo ainda não mapeado no `join`

No seu primeiro `join` você tenta acessar `ImportaContratosAux.ContratoId` que só está sendo carregado no segundo `join` a `query` deveria ser:

```
select 
    AreaReclamacao.Descricao 
from AreaReclamacao 
    inner join ImportaContratosAux  on ImportaContratosAux.EmpresaId    = AreaReclamacao.EmpresaId 
    inner join Contrato             on Contrato.Id                      = ImportaContratosAux.ContratoId
where Contrato.Id = '4100001124'
```

Veja que primeiro é carregado o `ImportaContratosAux` para depois realizar o `join` com `Contrato`